# How to write unit test for javascript revealing module pattern with Jest?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, revealing-module-pattern

For example: my math_util.js is

```
var MathUtil = function(){
  function add(a,b){
    return a + b;
  }
  return {
    add: add
  };
}
```

I'll use Jest to test add().  So I'll write

```
test('add', ()=>{
  expect(MathUtil().add(1,1)).toBe(2);
});
```

But I get `MathUtil` is undefined or `MathUtil()` is not a function.

I also tried to use `require()` or `import`.  But `MathUtil` doesn't have `module.export` or `export`.

So how to write unit test for javascript revealing module pattern with Jest?

Note: I've a project with all scripts written in revealing module pattern so convert all to ES2015 module may not be practical.

Comment: Do you even have the `MathUtil` function in scope for your tests? It seems that the test doesn't import it in any way.

Comment: How to add `MathUtil` to scope?  `MathUtil` doesn't have any export so I don't think I can use import.

Comment: If you've written an entire project this way, how do your other files find your utility function?

Comment: I inherited the project and every single files have been written in this way.  So all objects are accessed via `window`.  The application has access to `window.MathUtil`, but this doesn't work for Jest.  Btw `MathUtil` is just an example to show how codes are written in this project.

Comment: @Chanh you'll have to rewrite everything to add exports/imports. There is no `window` in node and top-level var declarations aren't in the global scope the way they are in the browser. Have you though about using an in-browser test runner and phantom?

Comment: @JaredSmith for the sake of completeness: the default Jest environment is jsdom which includes a `window` object and it is possible to use [setupFiles](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html#setupfiles-array) to set up things like global variables...that said, I agree that modules are definitely best practice.

Comment: @Chanh what was the aswer to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you *really* want to test `math_util.js` exactly as it is written you can do this:

```
// ---- math_util.test.js ----
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const vm = require('vm');

const code = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, '/math_util.js'), 'utf-8');
const MathUtil = vm.runInThisContext(code + '; MathUtil');

test('add', ()=>{
  expect(MathUtil().add(1,1)).toBe(2);
});
```

...but best practice would be to refactor the code into modules.  For the [revealing module pattern](https://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#revealingmodulepatternjavascript) that should be a very straightforward process, just remove the outer wrapping function and returned object, and put `export` in front of anything that was in the returned object:

```
// ---- math_utils.js ----
export function add(a,b){
  return a + b;
}


// ---- math_utils.test.js ----
import { add } from './math_utils';

test('add', ()=>{
  expect(add(1,1)).toBe(2);
});
```

Comment: So there's no way to add `MathUtil` to `window` for Jest to access like calling `window.MathUtl` inside `test()`? I'm afraid that updating every files to have `module.exports` is the only option.

Comment: While the information in this answer is correct, it doesn't actually answer the question.

Comment: @Chanh I updated my answer with how to test it without modifying math_utils.js

Answer (score 0):

You can use `babel-plugin-rewire` for this. Check this post: https://www.samanthaming.com/journal/2-testing-non-exported-functions/